# Is it possible to have a space in the directory name of a Structure Group?

Tags: 2011

Looking to have an output directory on content delivery that has a space in the directory name.

```
"D:\Data\webdocs\wwwroot\hello world"
```

Looks like the Tridion schema for Structure Groups don't allow it in the directory. Any way to get this?

Running Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a hotfix contained in the SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2 that solves my issue:

Hotfix 84000 Structure Groups do not allow spaces in directory name.

**Version**  This hotfix concerns SDL Tridion 2011 SP1HR1.
**Problem**  Structure Groups do not allow spaces in directory name. This also applies for the publication path and publication images path.
**Hotfix description**  Directory validation check has been altered and now support spaces as well.
**Distributed files** Tridion.ContentManager.Common.dll (File Version 6.1.0.997)
**Fixes included** None
**Dependencies**  None

Comment: **Note** with the Hotfix above and Tridion 2013, the steps noted by @EricHuiza must be followed.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible by modifying the regular expression for directories.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Directory">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
        <xsd:pattern value="[-a-zA-Z0-9!\(\)_~. ]*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

The modifications are done in `%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\cm_xml_usr.xsd`

After doing the changes you should restart the COM+ application and the Service Host Windows Service.

Comment: Eric has this exactly right, just keep in mind that this is not typically considered a good practice, and can lead to strange results in different web servers/browsers

Comment: May have spoke too soon on success :( I have made the above changes to allow for a space...but my xsd restriction does not seem to be the issue. ---Error when I violate restriction:
Invalid value for property 'Directory'. The value violates user schema constraints. The Pattern constraint failed.
---Error when the directory has a space:
Invalid value for property 'Directory'. 'translation manager' is not a valid path. Is something else restricting the space in the directory?